# Logstash output to Azure blobstorage

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logstash

I am currently importing IIS-logs into Logstash using Filebeat, and the Logstash is configured to output the documents into Elasticsearch.
Now I also want to output my IIS logs to Azure storage (blob) for longtime-backup purposes, but I cannot find a way to do it.

There is a working [Logstash plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html) for output to AWS. But I need to use Azure blob storage. 
I cannot find an output plugin for Azure Blobstorage in [the elastic output list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/output-plugins.html), or anywhere else..

**Is there a way to output documents from Logstash to Azure blobstorage?**

Seems like a valuable feature. I guess it would look like something below.

```
output {
    Azure_storage {
        account => "test"
        key => "SuperSecret"
        container => "Backup_Documents"
        blobName => "nameofblob"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one in the official plugins, nor in the community-maintained list of plugins. Someone probably hasn't written one yet. Or if they have, they aren't sharing. This may be a case where you output to a local directory and use a scheduled task to sync the directory to blob-storage. We're using this method for one of our stranger workflows.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source plugin:
https://github.com/tuffk/Logstash-output-to-Azure-Blob

Basic configuration:

```
  output {
       azure {
         storage_account_name => "my-azure-account"    # required
         storage_access_key => "my-super-secret-key"   # required
         container_name => "my-container"              # required
         size_file => 1024*1024*5                      # optional
         time_file => 10                               # optional
         restore => true                               # optional
         temporary_directory => "path/to/directory"    # optional
         prefix => "a_prefix"                          # optional
         upload_queue_size => 2                        # optional
         upload_workers_count => 1                     # optional
         rotation_strategy_val => "size_and_time"      # optional
         tags => []                                    # optional
         encoding => "none"                            # optional
       }
     }
```

To make the plugin available in your Logstash environment, run the following command:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-azure
```

Comment: This plugin is unfortunately no longer maintained.